# How to create a grid that includes resizable divs - never exceeds the size of the main container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am able to create the grid using a for loop. I then prompt for the number of rows and number of columns as the x and y values, respectively. I am having trouble understanding how one would go about creating divs that resize to fit the size of a container - with the container never exceeding the size of the page(?). Any suggestions?

```js
let x = parseInt(prompt("how many rows?"));
let y = parseInt(prompt("how many columns?"));

const reset = document.getElementById("reset");

reset.addEventListener("click", function() {
  location.reload();
});

const container = document.getElementById("container");

const rows = document.getElementsByClassName("gridRow");
const cells = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");

function makeGrid() {
  makeRows(x);
  makeCols(y);
}

function makeRows(rowNum) {
  for (i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {
    let row = document.createElement("div");
    container.appendChild(row).className = "gridRow";
  }
}

function makeCols(colNum) {
  for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < colNum; j++) {
      let col = document.createElement("div");
      rows[j].appendChild(col).className = "cell";
    }
  }
}

makeGrid();
```

```css
:root {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  min-width: 30px;
  min-height: 30px;
  margin: 4px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.cell:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.cell:active {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Etch-A-Sketch</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="reset" class="reset">RESET</button>
  <div id="container"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `vw` and `vh` css units ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Simon. I've tried to no avail. As a beginner, I can't seem to wrap my head around the concept. I am attempting to make it so my container div has a height and width of the size of the middle portion of my viewport - where the grid stretches or constricts to conform to that container. I'll keep messing around with the css and see what I come up with. Again, thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the whole question, but here is an example that will share the width and height of the grid itself.

The key is to use the `flex` layout and fix the initial grid size using `vw` and `vh` units.

I have simplified the code to focus on a minimal example.

```js
function makeCells(rows, columns) {
  let grid = document.getElementById("grid");
  
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    let row = document.createElement("div");
    row.className = "row";
    
    for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
      let column = document.createElement("div");
      column.className = "cell";
      row.appendChild(column);
    }
    
    grid.appendChild(row);
  }
}

makeCells(4, 3);
```

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  border: 1px solid red;
  
  width: 50vw; /* 50% of viewport width */
  height: 50vh; /* 50% of viewport height */
}

.row { 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100%;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid" class="grid"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Simon. Yesterday I watched a couple of videos on the topic and found a way to get it working. Thank you for your assistance, as your answer is exactly what I was looking for. Take care!